# Can't find the release for this wiring harness connector

Tags: wire, electric-motor

I am unable to unlock any "tabs". The video text just says use a slot screwdriver to release the locking tabs. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Harness with locking tabs]

Comment: We will need a lot clearer and close up picture to be able to help with this.

Comment: Are you sure you don't put a screw driver into that open slot on the female end of that connection?

Answer (score 4):

Picture is a bit fuzzy to be certain, but typical for this sort of connector would be to slide a flat screwdriver up the center (between the ridges on the left part) to pry up a tab sticking down from the end of the slot on the right part. Or, to lift the end of the slot off a tab sticking UP from the left part.

Or, sometimes, the screwdriver goes in the slot, from the right. Picture is not clear enough to tell which flavor you have, either try it, or take a better/bigger/clearer picture.

They can be pretty stiff to get apart even when unlocked, depending how long they have been together and how tight everything is. You also need 3 hands sometimes, as the locking tab won't STAY out unless you can actually get the screwdriver under it, and sometimes there isn't room, without breaking the connector, so you need someone to pry and someone to pull at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This video described what Ecnerwal said to do:

https://youtu.be/d6u5B6dJRVg?t=100

At 1:40 you'll see the flat screw driver pushed alongside the male portion of the connector into the female portion of the connector.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. If this is the best answer, you can mark it as such by clicking the checkmark icon.